# Nutanix VM template options

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, nutanix

I have been given access to the Nutanix prism console to manage the state of the VMs,etc. I see there is a VM template available and when choosing the option to Create VM from Catalog Item don't see the boot configuration option I intend to see.

Is there a possibility I can maintain the boot configuration options in the VM template i.e. Legacy Bios or UEFI Bios mode when creating the VM.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

For creating VMs in Prism Central on cluster that run on AHV hypervisor, [this document](https://portal.nutanix.com/page/documents/details?targetId=Prism-Central-Guide-vpc_2022_6:mul-vm-create-acropolis-pc-t.html) describes setting boot configuration in  Resources section of procedure